# More counters in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I'm having a problem with CSS counters.

I set up two counters: one indexes `headings` and other indexes `images`. However, only one works correctly, the other one (for images) shows only number 1 in all image descriptions. You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jddkucs7/)

```css
body {
  counter-reset: figcounter;
  counter-reset: head2counter;
}
.fig:before {
  counter-increment: figcounter;
  content: "Fig. " counter(figcounter)": ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
.figreset {
  counter-reset: figcounter;
}
.head2:before {
  counter-increment: head2counter;
  content: counter(head2counter)" ";
}
.head2reset {
  counter-reset: head2counter;
}
```

```html
<h1>Article title</h1>
<h2 class="head2">Services</h2>
<img src="http://www.google.com/about/company/images/company-products.png" width="200" />
<span class="fig">Google services</span>
<h2 class="head2">E-mail clients</h2>
<h2 class="head2">Others</h2>
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png" width="200" />
<span class="fig">Google logo</span>
<br />
<img src="http://thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/02/google_chrome.png" width="200" />
<span class="fig">Chrome</span>
```

Do you know how to fix it? If there is only one counter, it works correctly. I want to index images independently on `headings`.

Comment: Updated - added CSS code. Working demo is on http://jsfiddle.net/jddkucs7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from:

```css
body {
      counter-reset: figcounter;
      counter-reset: head2counter;
}
```

To:

```css
body {
    counter-reset: figcounter head2counter;
}
```

Why?

Because the `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` can be overridden.
 So if you have to use `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` for
 more than 1 element counter variable, you need to put them on the same declaration  for `counter-reset` and `counter-increment`, with a space separating them.
In this case you only need to put the `counter-reset` property

---

```css
body {
  counter-reset: figcounter head2counter;
}
.fig:before {
  counter-increment: figcounter;
  content: "Fig. " counter(figcounter)": ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
.figreset {
  counter-reset: figcounter;
}
.head2:before {
  counter-increment: head2counter;
  content: counter(head2counter)" ";
}
.head2reset {
  counter-reset: head2counter;
}
```

```html
<h1>Article title</h1>
<h2 class="head2">Services</h2>
<img src="http://www.google.com/about/company/images/company-products.png" width="200" />
<span class="fig">Google services</span>
<h2 class="head2">E-mail clients</h2>
<h2 class="head2">Others</h2>
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png" width="200" />
<span class="fig">Google logo</span>
<br />
<img src="http://thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/02/google_chrome.png" width="200" />
<span class="fig">Chrome</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm strange, your fiddle works, if you change your css to:

```
.fig {
  counter-increment: figcounter;
}
.fig:before {
  content: "Fig. " counter(figcounter) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jddkucs7/2/

But sorry, I have no idea why your fiddle doesn't work. May someone has any suggestions. I would be interested in an explanation too.

Ciao
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

your counter for the figcounter is not correctly keeping the count because it resets the counter after every span. what you want is to have a parent that needs to keep the count.

So in your example , if you enclose the section where you want the counter not to reset inside a div element , then it will work.

Refer the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) for more understanding and if my explanation was as clear as mud.

here is the snippet,

```css
body {
  counter-reset: figcounter;
  counter-reset: head2counter;
}
.fig:before {
  counter-increment: figcounter;
  content: "Fig. " counter(figcounter)": ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
.figreset {
  counter-reset: figcounter;
}
.head2:before {
  counter-increment: head2counter;
  content: counter(head2counter)" ";
}
.head2reset {
  counter-reset: head2counter;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Article title</h1>


  <h2 class="head2 figreset">Services</h2>


  <img src="http://www.google.com/about/company/images/company-products.png" width="200" /> <span class="fig">Google services</span>


  <h2 class="head2 figreset">E-mail clients</h2>


  <h2 class="head2 figreset">Others</h2>


  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png" width="200" /> <span class="fig">Google logo</span>

  <br />

  <img src="http://thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/02/google_chrome.png" width="200" /> <span class="fig">Chrome</span>

</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Take a look at OP's question here "I want to index images independetly on headings", your answer doesn't match OP needs :)

Comment: @dippas -  Ok It could work even then. All you have to do is tell the counter to reset. So if we just take the 'div' elements out and just give the class 'figreset' to the header 'h2' elements. that will reset it as well. I will update my answer to reflect that as well

Comment: interesting idea to reset index in every section with this method, might be also useful.